# Download selected file from telegram?

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-upload

Using python `telegram-upload` API I was able to upload the file to telegram cloud and also I stored the corresponding `file_id` of that file. Now this API provides `telegram-download` method which downloads all files from my telegram cloud, My question is how can I download some selected files only with help of `file_id` that I am storing. Is it possible using some other method?

Comment: I think yes, it is possible. Can you provide a code example to see where is your problem or to better understand what tools do you use. Links to them would be great.

Comment: @wowkin2 I am using this https://pypi.org/project/telegram-upload/  to upload and download files from telegram. and in the documentation it is not mentioned how to download individual files. Calling telegram download simply downloads all the files

Answer (score 0):

You can download a file first then you send it using your code. I recommend to use telethon library to upload file faster.
Also you can use transload links to upload without downloading which uploads a file faster.